# Homotopy type of complement to a union of linear subspaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology

Im not sure if this question is appropriate for MO, but I'm looking for a hint about some questions about homotopy type of complement to a union of linear subspaces in vector space $\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{H}^n$. More precisely:

1. How to rigorously prove that complement to a union of countable number of subspaces of codimension $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^n,\ n\geqslant r$, is $r-2$-connected?
2. How to prove that complement to a union of  countable number of subspaces of codimension 2 in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is always $K(\pi,1)$ space?
3. How to find homotopy type of a complement to a union of a finite number of arbitrary subspaces given by an equations $x_{i_1}=x_{i_2}=\ldots=x_{i_k}=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $ \mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{H}^n$ ($x_r$ means r-th real, complex or quaternion coordinate respectively) in general? In some  cases its possible to find that  type "by hands", and those problems are quite hard.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The keyword here is "arrangements". There are textbooks devoted to the topology of subspace arrangements (I think there's one by Orlik and Terao) which should discuss these questions.

Comment: If you search for "topology of hyperplane arrangements" on Amazon, the top three books are all dedicated to this topic.  There are a few other relevant conference proceedings, as well.